# Javascript equivalent for .width() and .height()

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

What is javascript equivalent for the following jquery code

```
  $(document).on({
    mousemove: function(event) {
        widget = $('.widget').last();
        x = event.pageX;
        y = event.pageY;

        widget.width(x); // here is the real problem
        widget.height(y); // here is the real problem
      }
    },
  });
```

Comment: From the [source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css.js#L243): `style[ name ] = value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
widget = $('.widget').last()[0];
x = event.pageX;
y = event.pageY;

widget.style.width  = `${x}px`;
widget.style.height = `${y}px`;
```